# New to fabric.io, how to use this for Android app?

Tags: android, twitter

I am new to fabric.io. How to integrate and use this for finding crashing data?

I've followed the official documentation but still I am not able to run my app using this.

Still in website it showing you have to run the app!

[see this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m54XY.png)

This is the thing it shows after done this steps

[see this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V8Gu.png)

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: yup am using Android Studio

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: no i installed in android studio .. then am not getting how to integrate to my app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I have actually played with Fabric. If you have not done so, installed the plugin for Android Studio. Once installed, you can use the plugin to add Crashlytics to your project. It can automatically add the code necessary to your project for it to work. After that build and run your application on a device.

1. Open the Fabric plugin from one of the two buttons. [image: Open the Fabric plugin from one of the two buttons.]
2. Click on the icon that looks like a power icon. [image: Click on the icon that looks like a power icon.]
3. Select organization to use. [image: Select organization.]
4. Select kit to use, in this case Crashlytics. [image: Select kit to use.]
5. Install the kit selected by pressing install. [image: install kit.]
6. Apply the changes to be made to your code. [image: Apply changes.]
7. Run application on a device. [image: Run app]
8. After the application runs, the plugin will show that Crashlytics is installed and keep pressing back until you get to your application in the plugin.[image: Verify and go back.]

And that is it. The plugin REALLY makes it easy.

Comment: i installed !! in android studio .. but it showing zero apps selected

Comment: please help me out this ! i want to use this

Comment: Okay, updated my answer with more, um, detailed steps. Beware the detail!

Comment: thanks for reply I did same steps but in my case its showing red color in installed