# How to add new version of app to fabric.io?

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter-fabric

I want to add new version of my application to fabric. How can i do this? I am new in fabric.io. I see this [New to fabric.io, how to use this for Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155195/new-to-fabric-io-how-to-use-this-for-android-app) but I can not see fabric button in android studio. please help me.

Comment: I find my problem but now have a bad question. I set new version of my app into fabri. now when I generate .apk file any crash and other details in  fabric will be shown?